# Print only specific part of lines from a command output

Tags: text-processing, awk

My command output is like this

```
                                Name: SLP_DCEMA100BAK01.1M__GBLON500BAK04.6M

 Operation  1                Use for: 0 (backup)

                             Storage: stu_disk_dcema100bak01

                     Retention Level: 3 (1 month)

 Operation  2                Use for: 1 (duplication)

                             Storage: stu_cc_gblon500bak04

                     Retention Level: 6 (6 months)
```

I want to print only those part that comes after ":"

Expected output is Like below

```
SLP_DCEMA100BAK01.1M__GBLON500BAK04.6M

0 (backup)

stu_disk_dcema100bak01

3 (1 month)

1 (duplication)

stu_cc_gblon500bak04

6 (6 months)
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove everything up through (and including) the last `:` on each line,
use

```
sed 's/.*://'
```

For example,

```
your_command | sed 's/.*://'
```

If your data (the part after the label, which you want to keep)
might contain a `:`,
you want to remove everything up through the *first* `:` in the line:

```
sed 's/^[^:]://'
```

If you have a space after the colon (as shown in your example)
and you want to remove that, too,
just add a space after the colon in the command:

```
sed 's/.*: //'
```

or

```
sed 's/^[^:]: //'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: '{sub(/^ /,"",$2);print $2}' file

SLP_DCEMA100BAK01.1M__GBLON500BAK04.6M

0 (backup)

stu_disk_dcema100bak01

3 (1 month)

1 (duplication)

stu_cc_gblon500bak04

6 (6 months)
```